# what is this mushroom and how to grow this mushroom?

Tags: species-identification, mycology, mushroom

What is this mushroom?

[image]

And how to grow this?

Comment: If I knew how to grow this particular mushroom, I would start a side business doing exactly that. They are very marketable.

Comment: Please add the location the picture is from

Comment: i find this in my village forest  in india himanchal pardesh kinnaur purbani

Comment: SEARCH "MOREL CULTIVATION", it is difficult, technical, requires good rainwater / special water and good microclimate, and it's low production quantities. some people cultivate morels. experienced pickers can find many of them in certain places. its interesting. the best thing is to put them in blender with other ingredients and throw all the spores everywhere shadey rainy and well drained. i found this vid for example https://youtu.be/lTFugHA2WaI?t=310

Comment: Regarding how to grow it, try https://gardening.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 7):

This is an Ascomycota from the genus [*Morchella*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morchella), called morel:

[image]

Morels are edible: despite the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morchella) page I linked above saying that *Morchella* has [hydrazine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrazine), according to Ammirati, Traquair and Horgen (1986):

> There is no evidence that *Morchella* species contain gyromitrin* or related compounds.

<sup>* A hydrazine compound.</sup>

Source: [Ammirati, J., Traquair, J. and Horgen, P. (1986). Poisonous mushrooms of the northern United States and Canada. 1st ed. Minneapolis: University of Minnesota Press](https://books.google.com.au/books?id=nhWbsGB7z4cC&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false).

PS: Your second question (*"how to grow this?"*), however, seems to be off topic here at Bio SE.